# Eclipse RCP application key bindings conflicts with typing in textbox

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I've assign `W,A,S,D` as hotkeys for zooming/scrolling through the key bindings extension point, and those are global hotkeys. This causes an issue that I can't type `WASD` in textbox. How should I fix this? I was thinking to disable the hotkey or do something in the textbox `OnFocus` event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really think that <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> are good key bindings and if you still think they make for good global key bindings (both I doubt), you can use [key binding contexts](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FwrkAdv_keyBindings_contexts.htm) to make the binding only available when outside editing controls.

Once you have defined an `org.eclipse.ui.contexts` extension, assign this context to the respective key bindings thought the `contextId` attribute.

Now these key bindings are only available if the specified context is active. The `IContextService` can be used to activate and deactivate the context.

Use a [*display filter*](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FDisplay.html) to deactivate the context when entering an editing control like `Text`, `Spinner`, `StyledText`, etc. and to activate it when leaving such a control.

For example:

```java
Listener filter = new Listener() {
  IContextActivation activation;
  @Override
  public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
    if( isEditingWidget( event.widget ) ) {
      if( event.type = SWT.FocusIn ) {
        contextService.deactivateContext( activation );
      } else {
        activation = contextService.activateContext( "context id" );
      }
    }
  }
};
display.addFilter( SWT.FocusIn, filter );
display.addFilter( SWT.FocusOut, filter );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your Hotkeys. WASD are already mapped as single single pressed and as pressed in combination with `shift`. Use the normal arrow keys. It is not worth modifying every textbox just so you can use an unwisely chosen set of hotkeys

Comment: What if the application just has very few textboxes. And the WASD hotkeys are really handy.